# How to handle a TR click without the first and last TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Datatables Table with some random values in it. I would like to create a popup when the client clicks on the TR itself, but NOT on the first and the last TD of the table.

```
<table class="table href="#popup">
    <tr id="tr1">
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr2">
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr3">
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr4">
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My popup plugin works like, if an `href` link is called and the popup div's `id` equals to that `href` value, it automatically pops up.

However if someone clicks on the first or the last `TD`  do NOT want the popup to activate. Is it actually possible to achieve this somehow?

(The following solution should not be mentioned, because it would make the code look like a mess literally: if I select all the `TD` fields without the first and last, and add a `href` attribute to all of the selected `TD` elements.)

Any other suggestions are welcomed!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you click, the event is propagated from the child nodes to the parent nodes ([learn more here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)).

You can disable event propagation in both `td:first-child` and `td:last-child` elements inside your table in order to prevent your `tr` event handler from being reached.

I'd also suggest you to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to keep better performance.

```
$('.table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    alert('show popup'); 
});

$('.table').on('click', 'td:first-child, td:last-child', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/6QTrL/1/

Answer (score 2):

Just use this:

Using `:first-child` and `:last-child` with `not()`

```
$('table tbody tr td').not(":first-child").not(":last-child").click(function(
   //This will only be triggered on the td that are not the first or the last on a tr

))
```

Comment: I think you'd need to remove that last td in your selector or your first and last children won't be on the rows of the table.  I do like the solution though.

Comment: If i remove the last td the selector it will look only at the tr elements that are not the first or last on the tbody, that's why i'm adding it.

Comment: Roger.  I read the initial post wrong. I'll give you a +1 cause I think your solution is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks I forgot to add the stopPropagation, cause i didn't remembered the bubbling of the first handler on the tr.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle to accomplish that - [First and Last row now clickable](http://jsfiddle.net/VtoCorleone/xn7YE/1/)

I have the first and last row throwing an alert but that's just to give you an idea of how to target them.

```
$(function(){
    var tableRows = $('table').find('tr');

    $('table').on('click', 'tr', function(){

        if (this == tableRows[0])
            alert('first row');
        else if (this == tableRows[tableRows.length - 1])
            alert('last row');
        else
            alert('somewhere in the middle');
    });    
});
```

The code below is probably more along the lines of what you're looking for.  I made the code above in the fiddle so I just pasted that as well.

```
$(function(){
    var tableRows = $('table').find('tr');

    $('table').on('click', 'tr', function(){
        if (this != tableRows[0] && this == tableRows[tableRows.length - 1])
            alert('somewhere in the middle');
    });    
});
```